# How to make browser loading/spinner bar active on some lazy operation?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loading

When I perform http requests I want my browser to make active its loading bar, I don't want to use custom spinners.
This is implemented by routing and ui-router components, so I think there is a possibility to make it, but cant find any docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loading bar of your browser is only activated if you perform an synchronous request. BUT: you don't want to do that, the user interface will become unresponsive. See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests

> In short, synchronous requests block the execution of code which creates "freezing" on the screen and an unresponsive user experience.

Answer (score 4):

Try this library, its super easy:

http://chieffancypants.github.io/angular-loading-bar

Inject into app module & it just works:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['chieffancypants.loadingBar'])
```

Comment: OP explicitly stated that custom visual spinners are out of question.